# If error is equal to _ do this Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Today I'm trying to make something in javascript / jQuery that does this; When an error occurs, this error for example

`Refused to display 'http://example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.`

The script will run a function to redirect them to the website they where going to.

Comment: There's always try/catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
try{
  //some bug
}
catch(ex){
  if(ex=="Some Error Message"){
    //do something here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something with try/catch

```
try {
    //some code to do
} catch(exc){
    if(exc == "Refused to display 'http://example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'."){
        //your redirect code here
    }
}
```

If the error is something else just replace `Refused to display 'http://example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.` with your error

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 What do you mean

Comment: `exc` (previously as `error` in your last edited answer) [isn't a string](http://jsfiddle.net/tGLaV/). You shouldn't compare it directly to a string and depend on the automatic type casting.